# Object to array in angularjs

Tags: arrays, angularjs

currently i am getting objects value in $scope.validuser but i want this into array form how do i store object value to array i jst want to store $scope.validuser into array i.e array[object]

```
  $scope.sportIds = [];
            angular.forEach($scope.users, function(value, key){
                $scope.sportIds[value.sport_id] = value.sport_id;
                if($scope.sportIds[value.sport_id] == 3){
                  $scope.validuser = value;
                  }
              });
```

Comment: Very unclear. Let's say your object is `{id: 42, name:'Jimmy', age: 27}`. What should the array contain?

Comment: As far as I could understand your question, you want `$scope.validuser` to be an array, including the value at each index - right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you an array containing only the valid users:

```
$scope.validuser = $scope.users.filter(function(user) {
  return user.sport_id === 3;
});
```